# Data URIs not working in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, filereader

I have this fileReader code

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileReader.onload = (function(file) {
        return function(e) {
            z = z + 40;
            // Place the image inside the dropzone
            var image = this.result;
            $('#dropped-files').append('<div style="left: ' + z + 'px; background: url(' + image + ') cover;"> </div>');

        };
    })(files[i]);
}​
```

Anyway, I'm trying to set the background of the appended box to the image that was just uploaded. The problem is it isn't working. The data URI is there but I can't seem to get it to show up as the background! Even when I click on the data URI link in inspect element I can get to the image that was uploaded, but it will not show up as the background image.

Any ideas why? The data URI is exceptionally long, but begins with the basic data and is base64, if that helps.

Comment: A demo or a link to the project would help.  The only thing coming to mind is that the floated div has no content to give it any width or height.

Comment: What is the format of your image variable.. just the first several characters should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `cover` at the end of the background value. I don't know what you're trying to do but adding it makes Chrome throw up its hands and say it isn't a valid property value.

EDIT:
Instead, make 2 declarations:

```
$('#dropped-files').append('<div style="left: ' + z + 'px; background: url(' + image + '); background-size: cover;"> </div>');
```

Comment: [`cover` is a `background-size` property value](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-cover.html).

Comment: ah i feel like such a fool now. Apparently background size has to be set separately.